# Is there Lashon Harah on Mi Yodea?

Tags: halacha, lashon-hara-slander

Being that on the whole users have screen names and there is a general air of anonymity. Is there an issue of Lashon Harah to refer to specific screen names when one has an issue with their tone of argument and overall behavior? Does it matter that we dont know the real identity? Does causing then a loss of online reputation have any halachic validity as it does not have real world consequences (eg. No real financial loss, no daily embarrassment)

Comment: You can definitely write lashon hara as well as speak it. If it's something posted in here it's more likely to be embarrassing someone in public than lashon hara. Lashon hara would apply in the Mi Yodeya chat though.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems that this may be more appropriate in Meta.

Comment: who said speaking it was muttar?

Comment: You can definitely write lashon hara as well as speak it.: that's a direct qoute from you

Comment: @Nafkamina He meant "can" as in "it's possible," not "it's permitted" Ch"V

Comment: Did the prior questions make his point about lost shidduchim? Because I think that's valuable

Comment: I don't know good point. But I'm assuming that goes into an average question of Lashon Harah ie. Causing damage to the person

Comment: @danf seems like a question of halacha not site policy. So main is the right site.

Comment: @SAH, I think a question that squarely asks about Loshon Harah in any context where there is no loss of money or reputation at stake even if the person could theoretically be identified is worth asking on its own. Mixing in the practical question of if that scenario expresses itself here ([it doesn't](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10693/loshon-hara-against-an-online-identity#comment15588_10753) in my view) just muddies the water, I think.