# When is anonymous negative speech lashon hara'?

Tags: mussar-ethics, lashon-hara-slander

When you speak negatively about someone, and your audience has no way of knowing what individual you are referring to, is it still considered lashon hara'? Source please.

Comment: A superset of this question: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10693/3

Comment: I agree to check WAF's link. I'm not sure it's a superset - may be a dupe. One area seems clear, though. If you are mentioning a known group of people as a group, I believe it is *lashon hara*.  if you extrapolate what one person did but apply it to a group - e.g. a Hassid stole something and you say, "All Hassidim are robbers", I think that's *lashon hara*.