# Is it loshon hora to downvote an answer on mi yodeya?

Tags: chofetz-chaim, loshon-hara

Is it loshon hora to downvote an answer on this website? I am asking this because perhaps it would be saying that someone has a bad answer, and maybe that would be giving off a bad impression of them.

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10693/loshon-hara-against-an-online-identity

Comment: Amoraim argue in the Gemoro; one disagrees with the view of the other. No implication is made as to the character/personality of the other. In MY we downvote the **content of the question or answer** and make no judgement as to the author.  So it should not be loshon hora.

Comment: In a case where the person is anonymous, I don't think it would be an issue. I generally try to avoid downvoting answers unless the answer was wrong (not incorrect, but bad) - but that's to avoid hurting someone's feelings, not lashon hara.